# SFINAE and std::numeric_limits

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I am trying to write a stream class that handles numerical and non-numerical data separately. Can someone explain to me why this code does not compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

class Stream
{
public:
    Stream() {};

    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer::value>>
    Stream& operator<<(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "I am an integer type" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    };

    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer::value>>
    Stream& operator<<(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "I am not an integer type" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Stream s;
    int x = 4;
    s << x;
}
```

Comment: You could *at least* post the compiler error (verbatim).. And, the details of the compiler in question. And your OS. Please try to provide *all* information that may be relevant *in the question*.

Comment: Won't actually solve the problem but `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer::value` should be `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer`.  There is no `value` member for `is_integer`

Comment: Additionally, you could just use [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are doing SFINAE wrong, and you are also incorrectly using the trait (there is no `::value`, `is_integer` is a boolean). The error with trait is trivial, the problem with SFINAE is that you gave a non-type template parameter to your `operator<<`, but you never provide an argument for it. You need to specify a default argument.

Sample code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

class Stream
{
public:
    Stream() {};

    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer>* = nullptr>
    Stream& operator<<(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "I am an integer type" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    };

    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer>* = nullptr>
    Stream& operator<<(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "I am not an integer type" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Stream s;
    int x = 4;
    s << x;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, so this resolves the second parameter to void* = nullptr correct?

Comment: @AdamSturge yes.